# How to use a single image file to display images/icons in a website

Tags: google-chrome, web-inspector, inspector

I have noticed that websites only using a single image png file to hold all the icons and images that website uses.  But when you inspect a specific image, you don't see the others.

**For example google.com images file as example:**

[image]

How is this image cut and spliced into individual images that are available to that webpage?

Comment: Are there any advantages of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is divided into "sprites". 
There is an example here http://www.spritecow.com/.

Code goes like this:

```
.sprite {
    background: url('imgs/example.png') no-repeat -433px -51px;
    width: 33px;
    height: 33px;
}
```

Comment: that code "background: url('imgs/example.png') no-repeat -516px -51px;" do the work, great, thank you!